Iterative PDE solver for 1D Burgers equation
I am looking for an Iterative Numerical PDE solver for 1D Burgers equation. I need to have access to the intermediate solutions of the Numerical Solver. By iterative methods, I mean techniques which start with an initial guess of the entire 2D grid u(x,t) and refine it iteratively. Although I came across multiple libraries which can solve 1D burgers, all of them generate the solution from time = 0 to the maximum_time. Whereas, I am looking for a solver which refines the solution for the whole space-time (2D in 1D burgers case) at once.

it sounds like you want a space-time finite element method, however even these methods typically have relatively short extents in time

Hi, I have some Matlab code (as @helloworld922 mentioned, it is a space-time FEM) which solves Burger's equation for 1+1D in fairly general fashion (for example, the interval can be time-dependent). This functionality is also implemented in MFEM (mfem.org) by my PhD supervisor's (Sander Rhebergen) research group (hence partially by me). We also have implemented all-at-once ST-HDG methods which can solve temporal PDEs (memory permitting) over the whole time span simultaneously.

It's hard to think of a good reason for rejecting the solvers you have found.  Perhaps if you can explain why you want an iterative solver, we might be able to help you better.  Otherwise there are some rather trivial ways to answer your question, but they probably aren't what you really want.

Why would you not want to solve the equation with a time stepping approach?

@WolfgangBangerth@DavidKetcheson By extracting the intermediate solution for the whole space time domain I will train a Neural Network which mimics the process of Numerical Solvers. Time stepping methods would not allow that; as the solution is not for the whole grid.

Hi @AbdullahAliSivas Can I have access to the code? It will be extremely helpful for me.

if you just need the solution at various times take a snapshot of the solution after taking a timestep, then stitch them together into a "2D" input space-time input for your network

@helloworld922 Actually I don't need the solution at various times; rather I am looking for a solver which solves for the span of whole time. At first it makes an initial guess (typically all zeros or random matrix), then refines it iteratively. For example : it the solution matrix is of shape (256,100) then first it creates an initial guess matrix of the same shape; and through an iterative process reaches the final solution. (similar to many machine learning algorithms; Later I will use Neural Network to mimic this process )

I will clean my matlab code up and put it into a github or gitlab repository. But it can take some time as it is not my priority. But you can use MFEM and follow my colleague Tamas Horvath's presentation titled "Space-Time Hybridizable Discontinuous Galerkin in MFEM" link: https://mfem.org/pdf/seminar/horvath.pdf to implement 1+1D Burger's Equation solver yourself. It is not terribly difficult
